# Cannot open database "aspnetdb" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\default'

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, aspnetdb

> [SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "aspnetdb" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\default'.] System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action'1 wrapCloseInAction) +6676046 System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +810 System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +4403 System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +84 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) +55 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) +368 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +6704814 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +6705315 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions) +610 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +1049 System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +74 System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +6707883 System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +78 System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +2192 System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource'1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +116 System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource'1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1012 System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource'1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +6712511 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource'1 retry) +152 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +229 System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHolder.Open(HttpContext context, Boolean revertImpersonate) +150 System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.GetConnection(String connectionString, Boolean revertImpersonation) +4876314 System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider.GetUsersInRole(String roleName) +1440 System.Web.Security.Roles.GetUsersInRole(String roleName) +335 mykladr.SiteMaster.Page_Init(Object sender, EventArgs e) +499 System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +186 System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +421 System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2098

My connection string in web.config is:

```
<add name="aspnetdbConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=kit-pc\;Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I am stuck with that issue, however I have seen some topics , which are the same i couldn't find an answer.

Comment: What exactly is not clear about this error message?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915360/exception-when-deploying-to-iis-login-failed-for-user-iis-apppool-defaultapppo

Comment: oooh thank you so much for quick and working answer that's really awesome thank you guys....)))))