# Login failed for user SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database-connection, connection-string

I am trying to connect to a local database but I am having problems with the creation of the connection string.

I found a small program on the internet to test my connection (see screenshot here: http://s21.postimg.org/vlgsq7rw7/image.jpg).

The program shows the connection as successful but when I use this connection string( same input as in the screen shot):

```
server=FlorinPilca-PC\SQLEXPRESS;database=DynamicWebServices"
```

I get the exception

> Login failed for user".

I tried all the users I could think of but none worked.

Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Check out [my prefered way of creating a usable connection string](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10480011/205233) - it will create a 100% compatible connection string without any 3rd party tools.

Comment: Have you tried connecting with 'sa' acoount?

Comment: I do not know what that client tool is doing, may be it has by default impersonate windows LOGIN and connecting using that. your connection string needs user/pass explicitly or something that tells to connect using impersonated windows authentication.

Comment: Filburt i tried what you told me and now the error is Message = "Cannot open database \"DynamicWebServices\" requested by the login. The login failed.\r\nLogin failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\\Serv'."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use if you use windows authentication

```
server=FlorinPilca-PC\SQLEXPRESS;database=DynamicWebServices;Integrated Security=True;
```

Comment: This is the new exception after doing what you told me:Message = "Cannot open database \"DynamicWebServices\" requested by the login. The login failed.\r\nLogin failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\\Serv'."

Comment: @user2761203 you can found the solution of this problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427300/login-failed-for-user-iis-apppool-myapppool

Comment: @user2761203 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915360/exception-when-deploying-to-iis-login-failed-for-user-iis-apppool-defaultapppo

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:
Data Source=FlorinPilca-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DynamicWebServices;User ID=mylogin;password=mypassword;